# Why data frame can not plotted in 3d graph in matplotlib?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, graph, keyerror

thank you for reading this. I am beginner with python and English.
I wanted to graph 3D graph with datasets- X,Y and Z from loaded csv file.
so I set x as the second column from csv file:

```
mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
f = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x = df[[1]]
y = df[[2]] 
z = df[[3]]

f.plot(x, y, z, label='vector')

plt.show()
```

but this code gave me:
KeyError: 0
How can I meke ithis to a graph? (each dataframe has 292307 rows.)

Thank you so much.

Comment: We need to know what kind of data it is. Should this be producing a 3d line plot, scatter plot, surface etc..?

A helpful resource for 3d plotting in matplotlib is [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#line-plots)

Comment: Thank you everyone I figured this out. Much appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is with pandas, not matplotlib. Use the following to get your column names:

```
df.keys()
```

and then you need to extract out the columns: 
say for example my column names are ["hi", "bye", "world"], then my commands are:

```
x = df["hi"]
y = df["bye"]
z = df["world"]
```

read through the pandas [indexing and selecting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) docs.